# How to add a click handler to a custom jQuery UI widget and use the widget's property in the handler?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, click, jquery-widgets, jquery-ui-widget-factory

I have prepared a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afarber/8nd2wa1f/) for my problem.

I define a custom jQuery UI widget representing a game table with up to 4 players and a white gid ("game id") number in the middle:

[image: screenshot]

Here is my code (same as in the jsfiddle):

```js
$(function() {
  var PHOTO_PATTERN = /^https:\/\/\S+/i;

  $.widget('raspasy.table', {
    // default options
    options: {
      gid: NaN,
      player0: null,
      player1: null,
      player2: null,
      player3: null
    },

    _create: function() {
      this.element.addClass('raspasy-table');

      this.gidDiv = $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'raspasy-table-gid'
      }).appendTo(this.element);
      this.player0 = $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'raspasy-table-player0'
      }).appendTo(this.element);
      this.player1 = $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'raspasy-table-player1'
      }).appendTo(this.element);
      this.player2 = $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'raspasy-table-player2'
      }).appendTo(this.element);
      this.player3 = $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'raspasy-table-player3'
      }).appendTo(this.element);

      this.rep0 = $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'raspasy-player-rep'
      }).appendTo(this.player0);
      this.bad0 = $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'raspasy-player-bad-small'
      }).appendTo(this.rep0);
      this.good0 = $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'raspasy-player-good-small'
      }).appendTo(this.rep0);

      this.rep1 = $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'raspasy-player-rep'
      }).appendTo(this.player1);
      this.bad1 = $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'raspasy-player-bad-small'
      }).appendTo(this.rep1);
      this.good1 = $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'raspasy-player-good-small'
      }).appendTo(this.rep1);

      this.rep2 = $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'raspasy-player-rep'
      }).appendTo(this.player2);
      this.bad2 = $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'raspasy-player-bad-small'
      }).appendTo(this.rep2);
      this.good2 = $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'raspasy-player-good-small'
      }).appendTo(this.rep2);

      this.rep3 = $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'raspasy-player-rep'
      }).appendTo(this.player3);
      this.bad3 = $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'raspasy-player-bad-small'
      }).appendTo(this.rep3);
      this.good3 = $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'raspasy-player-good-small'
      }).appendTo(this.rep3);

      this._refresh();
    },

    _destroy: function() {

      this.good0.remove();
      this.bad0.remove();
      this.rep0.remove();

      this.good1.remove();
      this.bad1.remove();
      this.rep1.remove();

      this.good2.remove();
      this.bad2.remove();
      this.rep2.remove();

      this.good3.remove();
      this.bad3.remove();
      this.rep3.remove();

      this.player0.remove();
      this.player1.remove();
      this.player2.remove();
      this.player3.remove();

      this.gidDiv.remove();

      this.element.removeClass('raspasy-table');
    },

    _setOptions: function() {
      this._superApply(arguments);
      this._refresh();
    },

    _drawPerson: function(playerDiv, badDiv, goodDiv, playerJson) {
      if (playerJson) {
        var photo = (PHOTO_PATTERN.test(playerJson.photo) ? playerJson.photo : 'https://raspasy.de/raspasy/images/male_happy.png');
        playerDiv.css('background-image', 'url("' + photo + '")');
        var rep = parseFloat(playerJson.rep);
        if (0 <= rep && rep <= 1) {
          var w = badDiv.width();
          badDiv.height(w * (1 - rep)).show();
          goodDiv.height(w * rep).show();
        } else {
          badDiv.hide();
          goodDiv.hide();
        }
        playerDiv.show();
      } else {
        playerDiv.hide();
      }
    },

    _refresh: function() {
      this.gidDiv.text('#' + this.options.gid);

      this._drawPerson(this.player0, this.bad0, this.good0, this.options.player0);
      this._drawPerson(this.player1, this.bad1, this.good1, this.options.player1);
      this._drawPerson(this.player2, this.bad2, this.good2, this.options.player2);
      this._drawPerson(this.player3, this.bad3, this.good3, this.options.player3);

      this.player0.css('transform', 'rotate(' + (4 - 8 * Math.random()) + 'deg)');
      this.player1.css('transform', 'rotate(' + (4 - 8 * Math.random()) + 'deg)');
      this.player2.css('transform', 'rotate(' + (4 - 8 * Math.random()) + 'deg)');
      this.player3.css('transform', 'rotate(' + (4 - 8 * Math.random()) + 'deg)');
    }
  });

  // MAIN SCRIPT

  var tablesList = $('#tablesList').selectable();
  var table1 = $('<li/>').appendTo(tablesList).table({
    gid: 3
  });
  var table2 = $('<li/>').appendTo(tablesList).table({
    gid: 104,
    player0: {
      rep: Math.random()
    }
  });
  var table3 = $('<li/>').appendTo(tablesList).table({
    gid: 115,
    player0: {
      rep: Math.random()
    },
    player1: {},
    player2: {
      rep: Math.random(),
      photo: 'https://raspasy.de/raspasy/images/male_sad.png'
    },
    player3: {
      rep: Math.random(),
      photo: 'https://raspasy.de/raspasy/images/female_happy.png'
    }
  });
  var table4 = $('<li/>').appendTo(tablesList).table({
    gid: 116,
    player0: {
      photo: 'https://raspasy.de/raspasy/images/female_happy.png'
    },
    player1: {
      rep: Math.random(),
      photo: 'https://raspasy.de/raspasy/images/female_sad.png'
    },
    player2: {
      rep: Math.random(),
      photo: 'https://raspasy.de/raspasy/images/male_sad.png'
    },
    player3: {
      rep: Math.random(),
      photo: 'https://raspasy.de/raspasy/images/female_happy.png'
    }
  });

  table1.click(function() {
    console.log('table clicked: ' + this.gid);
    alert('table clicked: ' + this.gid);
  });
  table2.click(function() {
    console.log('table clicked: ' + this.gid);
    alert('table clicked: ' + this.gid);
  });
  table3.click(function() {
    console.log('table clicked: ' + this.gid);
    alert('table clicked: ' + this.gid);
  });
  table4.click(function() {
    console.log('table clicked: ' + this.gid);
    alert('table clicked: ' + this.gid);
  });

});
```

```css
.raspasy-table {
  position: relative;
  background: #A3DD8E;
  color: white;
  margin: 50px;
  float: left;
  border: 4px solid #91BCE5;
  border-radius: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 32px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
}

.raspasy-table:hover {
  background-color: #92CC7D;
}

.raspasy-table-gid {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  top: 65px;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.raspasy-table-player0 {
  position: absolute;
  left: -40px;
  top: 50px;
  background: #FFF no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  display: none;
}

.raspasy-table-player1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  top: -30px;
  background: #FFF no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  display: none;
}

.raspasy-table-player2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 120px;
  top: 50px;
  background: #FFF no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  display: none;
}

.raspasy-table-player3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  top: 130px;
  background: #FFF no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="tablesList"></ul>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

My problem is that the click is not working.

I have also tried:

```
table1.on('click', function (event, ui) {
  console.log('table clicked: ' + this.gid);
  alert('table clicked: ' + this.gid);
});
```

And:

```
table1._on( this.element, {
    'click': function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('table clicked: ' + this.gid);
        alert('table clicked: ' + this.gid);
    }
});
```

but still the click handler code is not called.

**UPDATE:**

I have tried adding the suggestion by Twisty (thank you!), which works perfectly in his jsfiddle:

```
  $("#tablesList").on("click", ".raspasy-table", function() {
    var myID = $(this).table("option", "gid");
    console.log('table clicked: ' + myID);
    alert('table clicked: ' + myID);
  });
```

but in my real app it is not working.

Is the click event maybe masked by `$('#tablesList').selectable();` line in my code?

When I inspect the `#tablesList` element it seems to have 2 event handlers. Is the first handler stealing the click event from the second one?

[image: game screenshot]

Comment: In your jsfiddle, do you see this Chrome Developer tool error in the console? Uncaught ReferenceError: table1 is not defined
    at ?editor_console=:378

Comment: I think it's a scope issue.

Comment: If you remove the code below `// MAIN SCRIPT` then errors disappear. So I think my question is still valid: how to add a click handler to each table widget and use the `gid` in the handler?

Comment: Did you just fix it?  I looked your code was outside of the document.ready function or $(function()

Comment: I've just fixed my typo (the misplaced brackets). But my problem is still not solved.

Comment: Since the `gid` is a part of the options, you can read it from the getter: `$(this).table("option", "gid");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address this, you will want to use an `.on()` for click and also call the `gid` via the Getter.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/6bmtnL1f/7/

**JavaScript**

```
  $("#tablesList").on("click", ".raspasy-table", function() {
    var myID = $(this).table("option", "gid");
    console.log('table clicked: ' + myID);
    alert('table clicked: ' + myID);
  });
```

I would advise moving this into the `_create` function. To do this, you add the `.click()` after the table has been created.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/6bmtnL1f/16/

Comment: Thank you for the great answer (as always by you). Could you please take a look at the updated question? If I have the `$('#tablesList').selectable();` then the click handler is not called.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber Selectable should not interfere, it just adds a Class to the items selected. IF you're seeing two event handlers, maybe one cannot bubble up over the other. I would suggest investigating or opening a new question.